# Handling Javascript cookie race conditions between windows

Tags: javascript, synchronization, race-condition

I am building a web application (using Fay to generate Javascript) where a user can have multiple tabs / windows open to the app. I want all open instances to collectively host a finite state machine, where there is only one state shared between all open windows / tabs. State transitions are triggered by events in windows and by timeouts. Timeouts need to happen as long as at least one window is still open, so I set them in all windows.

Because I want this system to work on older browsers as well, I don't want to use LocalStorage or Worker Threads to implement it, so instead I am trying to use cookies to communicate between windows. I also want most of this communication between windows to occur client side (i.e. I don't want to need to require a HTTP request to the server side for every state transition).

However, this creates a race condition: All open windows trigger the timeout at the same time, and potentially overwrite the cookie changes performed by each other on this state transition. I can reduce the window in which the race condition might occur by adding noise to the timeouts and by setting the new state cookie as soon as a timeout is hit, but because there doesn't seem to be an atomic way to read-and-update a cookie, the race is still there, just less likely to occur.

What cross-browser, purely client side synchronisation primitives are available in Javascript when communicating between windows on the same domain?

Comment: Just in case : don't all your windows have a common opener ? If so you could use it to communicate more directly and efficiently.

Comment: dystroy: Not necessarily - the user might have navigated to the domain again or used a bookmark to open a second instance of the page.